# XML or Resource (.resx) file

Tags: c#, xml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I'm developing a Windows 8.1 Store app and I have some text to add, but I'm not sure if it is better to use a resource file or a XML file.

This a piece of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<words>
    <word>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Teacher</name>
    </word>
    <word>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Pitcher</name>
    </word>
```

I have to deserialize a set of words (with an id and a name), and load it in a list of words. And I'm asking if it is better deserialized those objects from a XML or from a Resource file.

**What do you recommend me?**

Comment: You intend on supporting more than one language?

Comment: I have six files with words in six languages.

Comment: What use you make of the id? Must it absolutely be a sequential numeric, or would a string id do? Also, is "name" supposed to represent the *content* of the word? If so it's really not clear.

Comment: @Crono I'm not asking that. I have to deserialize a set of words (with an id and a name), and load it in a list of words. And I'm asking if it is better deserialized those objects from a XML or from a Resource file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is a Windows 8.1 Store app, this is how I have solved this problem:

```
private static async Task<List<Word>> GetWordsFromFileAsync(string folder, string file)
{
    List<Word> list = null;

    StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
    storageFolder = await storageFolder.GetFolderAsync(folder);

    // acquire file
    StorageFile storageFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(file);

    Stream readStream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(readStream);
    list = xDoc
            .Descendants("word")
            .Select(x => new Word 
            {
                Id = (int) x.Element("id"),
                Name = (string) x.Element("name")
            }).ToList();

    return list;
}
```

Thanks to [@Selman22](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3010968/selman22) to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Since Visual Studio has built-in compatibility with .resx files on Windows 8.x projects, I would recommend the Ressource file solution. Personally, I like using this approach with the excellent [ResXManager](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b64e04c-e8de-4b97-8358-06c73a97cc68?SRC=VSIDE) which makes it really simple.

Also, it will be simple to use those words in the XAML using a simple DataBinding, which can be a bit more complicated with the XML solution, since it's not built-in. So, why reinvent the wheel ?

Comment: RESX files won't help with the custom id and name element requirement.

Comment: This id and name requirements seem to be a solution more than a requirement. However, if you are right, than this is three efficient solutions : XML, JSON or binary serialization. However, I still think the .RESX files are better to store this kind of data.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you `LINQ to XML`, first create your class:

```
public class Word
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Then populate your list like this:

```
var words =  XDocument.Load("path")
                .Descendants("word")
                .Select(x => new Word 
                  {
                     Id = (int) x.Element("Id"), 
                     Name = (string) x.Element("Name")
                  }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

create a sample data class which will be used to store the XML element values:

```
public class Word
{
string name;
string id;

public string Name
{
    get { return name; }
    set { name= value; }
}

public string ID
{
    get { return id; }
    set { id= value; }
}
}
```

This how you read values from XML,

```
             var xElem = XElement.Load("XML/books.xml");
             var result=
                from elem in xElem.Descendants("Word")
                orderby elem.Attribute("name").Value
                select new Book
                {
                    Name = elem.Attribute("name").Value,
                    Id = elem.Element("Id").Value, 

                };
```